# Add a plot in the same figure as a previous plot

Tags: python

I have created a program that plots polynomials, which you can see down below:

```
def symbolic_derivative(xs):

    derivative_xs = []
    derivative_copy = xs.copy()

    if len(xs) == 0:
        return []

    derivative_copy.pop(0)

    for degree, term in enumerate(derivative_copy, start = 1):
        derivative_xs.append(term*degree)
    
    return derivative_xs

def eval_poly(p,x): 
    ans = 0
    for degree,coeff in enumerate(p): # vi använder oss av en for loop och enumerate för att kunna ta fram polynomets värde i en viss punkt x
        ans += coeff*x**degree # ekvationen som ska räknas
    return ans

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_poly(p,x_start=-10,x_end=10,color='b'):

    lst_x = list(range(x_start, x_end + 1))

    lst_y = [eval_poly(p,x) for x in lst_x]    

    plt.plot(lst_x, lst_y, color)
    plt.savefig('plot1.pdf')
    plt.show()
```

I then want to produce two plots `plot_poly([3,-1,2,1],-10,10,'b')` and `plot_poly(symbolic_derivative([3,-1,2,1]),-10,10,'r')` and I do this by typing them one at a time in the console box and it then prints out a plot for the respective command.

But I would like python to show these to in the same figure, so that after I have produced the first plot and it is displayed I would like it to continue to draw the second plot in the first figure and not in a new one. That is, python should add a plot in the same figure as the previous one. How can I do that?

This is how I want to work:

`>>> plot_poly([3,-1,2,1],-10,10,'b')`

[image]

`>>> plot_poly(symbolic_derivative([3,-1,2,1]),-10,10,'r')`

[image]

Comment: remove the plt.show()

Comment: @ombk if I to this it still continues to plot these in two different figures

Comment: then it might be smart to remove the function and plot them manually